# Python client data not being sent to java server entirely

Tags: java, python, sockets, serversocket, tcp

i have a python client that sends 400,000 data to java server but it is not being sent entirely. Sometimes 2446 make it to server and sometimes 2765. After receiving data, server writes it to notepad.

Here's what i am using to send data to java server from python client:`

```
  for x in range (0, 4000000):
        test =  "INSERT " + rstring(4) + " " + rstring(4) + " " + rdate() + "\n"
        client_socket.send(test)
```

And here's how i am reading it in my server

```
BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e1) {              
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }               
                try {
                    sy = br.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    sy = "";
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please read the [`socket.send` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send)...

Comment: To add to @Rawing's comment: the relevant part is *Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.*